# Build multiple C++ files not working - Linux Mint

Tags: c++, linux, visual-studio-code

I am following a C++ tutorial, and the guy shows how to set up tasks.json to run multiple C++ files at the same time, link with timestamp:
https://youtu.be/8jLOx1hD3_o?t=4584

Now I installed the newest versions of all of the packages:
[image]

Change my tasks.json to be same as his:

```
{
  "version": "2.0.0",
  "tasks": [
    {
      "type": "cppbuild",
      "label": "C/C++: g++-11 build active file",
      "command": "/usr/bin/g++-11",
      "args": [
        "-g",
        "-std=c++20",
        "${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp",
        "-o",
        "${fileDirname}/rooster"
      ],
      "options": {
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}"
      },
      "problemMatcher": ["$gcc"],
      "group": "build",
      "detail": "compiler: /usr/bin/g++-11"
    }
  ]
}
```

Try to compile and it does not work, error:

```
Starting build...
/usr/bin/g++-11 -g -std=c++20 "/home/elhan/ius/intro to programming/cpp/*.cpp" -o "/home/elhan/ius/intro to programming/cpp/rooster"
cc1plus: fatal error: /home/elhan/ius/intro to programming/cpp/*.cpp: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.

Build finished with error(s).
```

What might be the problem?

Working dir:
[image]

Comment: For the moment, I'm going to assume "now" means "not" in your title.

Comment: My guess is your `.cpp` files are not in that folder or don't have a .cpp extension: `/home/elhan/ius/intro to programming/cpp` Also remember that in linux your filesystem may be case sensitive so any file ending in  `.CPP` would not be found with `*.cpp`

Comment: Weren't all these fancy GUI IDEs, with their pretty dialogs and buttons, supposed to make things easier, to avoid all these icky `Makefile`s and command lines? You mean that you have to invoke some magic incantation in the form of a convoluted JSON file, to get basic functionality right? That's a darn shame, isn't it? Once your read `make`s man page, as lengthy as it is, with plenty of examples, it's pretty straightofrward to simply push `F5` in emacs, and get everything built.

Comment: The obvious question is, do you have any .cpp files in /home/elhan/ius/intro to programming/cpp/ ?

Comment: See edit for my working dir.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik - Amen brother. You want to learn C/C++? Here, learn `.json` first. Sheeze..., just open an xterm or command prompt and compile it there. No fuss, no muss, no hoping the IDE is doing things right. Orders of magnitude easier ....

Comment: You should avoid using spaces in paths and file names in `c++` however I don't think its a problem here because of the quotes.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik That's a weird way to suggest a build system. VS Code actually has native make support, and the cmake extensions are also very good. I would also suggest OP use a build system instead of messing with tasks.json. It's also worth pointing out that VS Code is **not** an IDE.

Comment: @Elco Strange, I don't see the problem.

Comment: Try `ls "/home/elhan/ius/intro to programming/cpp/*.cpp"` to double check your path is correct

Comment: Did that Youtube video tell you to create a directory with a name containing spaces?

Answer (score 0):

One of the arguments to your build command is

```
${workspaceFolder}/*.cpp
```

When variable substitution occurs, VS Code recognizes that there are spaces in your directory name, so the entire argument is enclosed in quotes to protect it from the shell. In the line after `Starting build...`, you can see the same thing happening with the argument specifying the output destination (which also has spaces after substitution), while the other arguments (with no spaces in them) are passed to the shell without quotes.

```
"/home/elhan/ius/intro to programming/cpp/*.cpp"
```

The quotes do indeed protect the argument from being processed by the shell, which is why it is interpreted as a single argument. At the same time, the quotes protect the argument from being processed by the shell, which is why the wildcard `*` is not expanded. And that's the problem.

If you pay attention to details, the video uses underscores instead of spaces to separate words in directory names. Follow suit, and rename your `intro to programming` directory to `intro_to_programming`.